# Android OutOfMemoryError Crash in startManagingCursor

Tags: android, database

I am getting a crash report back that says OutOfMemoryError in my call to startManagingCursor. Here is the returned stack trace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:123)
at android.app.Activity.startManagingCursor(Activity.java:1652)
at com.bubblewaretechnology.pianounlockscreen.LockDetecter.onResume(LockDetecter.java:633)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:1789)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:1795)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:124)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1015)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am very careful to close my cursors, SQLiteDatabase and SQLiteOpenHelper.  Here is a short code segment that the crash refers to:

```
Cursor callCursor = lockLib.getCallState();
startManagingCursor(callCursor);
....
callCursor.close();
```

Pretty stumped on how to go about troubleshooting this problem.  I know startManagingCursor is depreciated but I am not targeting HONEYCOMB or later, so I cant switch to  CursorLoader.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's lame to answer your own question but you can remove startManagingCursor,  [Reference Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startManagingCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29), as long as you are managing the lifecycle of your cursor appropriately.